# Swift optional chaining with NSDictionary

Tags: syntax, swift, xcode6, optional-values

Please help to remake this

```
 if let field = parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code) {
    if let stored_value = field["value"] as? String {
```

into optional chaining syntax in single line. I tried to do it like this:

```
let stored_value = parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code)?["value"] as? String
```

and got an error:

```
Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'
```

This is my function header:

```
func getFieldForCode(code: String) -> NSDictionary?
```

Is it possible? I ask it because any time I work with NSArrays and NSDictionaries my code looks terrible:

```
if let code = self.row_info["code"] as? String {
        if let value_field = self.row_info["value_field"] as? String {
            if let field = parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code) {
                if let stored_value = field["value"] as? String {
                    if let fields = self.fields_set{
                        if let current_value = fields[indexPath.row][value_field] as? String {
```

Any advices?

Comment: I believe you just need some parens:  `let stored_value = (parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code))?["value"] as? String`

Comment: No, I have the same error with parens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast it directly to a `String` because you're pulling it from an `NSDictionary` and, like the error says, `String` doesn't conform to `NSCopying`. However, `String` is bridged to `NSString`, and `NSString` **does** conform to `NSCopying`. So, with a little bit of casting/bridging trickery, you can make it work like this:

```
let stored_value: String? = parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code)?["value"] as? NSString
```

***Note:** If you're using this in an optional binding (which it looks like you want to), don't forget to drop the `?` from `stored_value`'s type declaration:*

```
if let stored_value: String = parent_obj?.getFieldForCode(code)?["value"] as? NSString {
    /* ... */
}
```